# How to select an Item from the Richfaces PickList sourceList using the javascript API?

Tags: javascript, richfaces

I'm working with **Richfaces 4.5.1 PickList component** and I need to select an item from the source list using javascript. I'm looking to the javascript API from the Richfaces documentation and i'm able to use getSourceList() and add() functions without a problem. The documentation says that getSourceList() will give you the javascript list object to where you can select/unselect item(s). The problem is that it doesn't tell you the function name to select/unselect items. I can't use add() without first selecting an item.

**Javascript function:**

```
function refresh() {
            var source = #{rich:component('customer')}.getTargetList();
            INSERT CODE TO SELECT FROM source LIST
            #{rich:component('customer')}.add();
        }
```

**Richfaces PickList:**

```
<rich:pickList id="customer" value="#{payrollCreate.nameList}" listHeight="200" sourceCaption="Available Customers" targetCaption="Selected Customers" orderable="true">
   <f:selectItems value="#{payrollCreate.clients}"/>
</rich:pickList>
```

can anyone help me with this? 
Thanks...

Comment: You don't need javascript for that, you can do it in Java.

Comment: I tried to do that. I have tried to do it in server and client side. for example when i refresh the page to show the changes it goes back initial state.

Comment: Set proper data in value attribute of pickList (subset of selectItems).